# Should i store all variable in ngrx/store?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I use Angular 4 with ngrx, I've stored most of the variables, properties that I fetch from a server ...
I wonder that, should be better if I store all variable ( like: graph data of chartjs, toggle show/hide of an element, ... ) I mean, all of the variables of the components should be stored in reducer ? and why it's better / worse

Comment: It's difficult to make out what you exactly want to know? What are you trying to do?

Comment: well this is kind of educational...